# Apache Ant & Java WSDL Import - fatal error

Tags: java, ant, wsdl2java

Our application is build on Java 7 and the other application is build on Java 8.
I have imported the wsdl url certificate using keytool & using Java 8 I'm able to generate the Jar. But when I use Java 7 it gives me `[ERROR] Received fatal alert: protocol_version`

I'm using `ant` to generate the jar.

```
<target name="abcService">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}/jar/" />
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}/abcService" />
        <echo message="building client classes....."/>
        <wsimport 
            debug="true" extension="true"  package="com.abc.abcService"             
            wsdl="https://abc-test1.corp.intranet/ABC/services/AbcServiceImplPort?wsdl" 
            destdir="${build.dir}/abcService">                  
            <xjcarg value="-XautoNameResolution"/>
        </wsimport>
        <echo message="Jarring the classes generated using wsimport..."/>
        <jar destfile="${build.dir}/jar/abcService.jar">
             <fileset dir="${build.dir}/abcService" />
        </jar>           
   </target>
```

Comment: If it works with Java 8 but not with 7, then it would be possible that the built-in encryption library is too old for the HTTPS connection. They may use an encryption protocol that Java 7 does not yet know. But that's just a guess. You can try adjusting the log level (but don't ask me how) to get a more descriptive error message.